# Error - Ruby OCI8 - Wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1)

Tags: sql, ruby, oracle, oci8

When running this script:

```
require 'oci8'

  conn = OCI8.new('username', 'password', 'tnsname')
  cursor = conn.exec('SELECT 1+1 FROM dual')

  while r = cursor.fetch()
    puts r.join(',')
  end

  cursor.close
  conn.logoff
```

The following error message occurs:

```
   C:/tech/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `initi
alize': wrong number of arguments (2 for 0..1) (ArgumentError)
        from C:/tech/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
:36:in `new'
        from C:/tech/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
:36:in `require'
        from C:/tech/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
:36:in `require'
        from C:/tech/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-oci8-2.1.5-x86-mingw3
2/lib/oci8.rb:81:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/tech/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
:60:in `require'
        from C:/tech/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
:60:in `rescue in require'
        from C:/tech/Ruby193/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb
:35:in `require'
        from u:/Ruby/test_oci_connect.rb:1:in `<main>'
```

I can use those credentials in SQLPLUS and I have both the gems and devkit installed. Can anyone assist with this issue or provide some clarity regarding the answer below?

Comment: I have reported same issue. But it hasn't been solved yet. See https://github.com/kubo/ruby-oci8/issues/42

Answer (score 1):

The issue is caused by a mismatch in the Oracle DLLs architecture and your Ruby installation, or your System not finding the right DLLs.

Download the [Oracle Instant Client](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/features/instant-client/index-097480.html). Its important that its the same arch that your Ruby is in, as it contains the necessary DLLs.

Unzip it somewhere on your HDD, such as:

```
C:/OracleInstantClient
```

Its also convenient to add both

```
/network/admin/sqlnet.ora 
/network/admin/tnsnames.ora
```

to that folder.

Add the Instant Client's location to your System PATH. You should now be able to connect without that error, provided you've added the correct connection information.

Comment: I had the Oracle Instant Client (32bit Version) installed already but I have set up new system variables as follows:
ORA_HOME - C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1
TNS_ADMIN - C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN (where the sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora files are). Unfortunately the same error is being returned.

Comment: I had the same issue. I found it was better to remove the double variables and just add the location to the System Path.

Comment: System Variable - PATH now contains: "C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin\NOTES\";"C:\Program Files\Business Objects\Common\3.5\bin\NOTES\DATA\";%SystemRoot%\system32;C:\tech\Ruby193\bin;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1;C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1\NETWORK\ADMIN - Still no change.

Comment: You just need to add the C:/[path to instant client] location to your PATH. Also, remember to restar the console.

Comment: SO I have entered this: `C:\oracle\product\10.2.0\client_1` into the PATH variable and I have added the sqlnet.ora and tnsnames.ora into that directory, however the same error is still occurring. Any more ideas?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the tnsnames.ora.
I am able to connect with the following code:

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same error message, using a gem dependent on ruby-oci8 (dm-oracle-adapter for datamapper).
Re-ran the install as per these instructions on a fresh environment :

[Installing instant client for ruby-oci8](http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/file.install-instant-client.html)

Double checked the path was set correctly and restarted my ruby console.
And everything worked perfectly.

On the machine it didn't work on (above incorrect arguments error), I have Oracle 64 bit dlls installed for some other services. My theory is that it was conflicting with these dlls (Ruby-oci8 needs 32bit DLLs), even though there was nothing pointing to these in the path.

Also, if you get the warning "ext/oci8 not found" when running 'gem install ruby-oci8', let me save you some time. In my case, this was a red herring and didn't affect the function of the gem at all.

Answer (score 0):

That problem doesn't seem related to OCI8 at all.

You are misleading us a little here by not showing the whole code.

From your error stack trace, I can tell that you have a class that's trying to initialize but you have defined a parameter to that method and you didn't mention it when creating your object.

What this really means is that you mentioned 2 parameters where it was expecting either nothing or just one parameter.

if you create a test.rb fiel and paste the code you show us above all by itself, does it work?